# How do I reproduce this SQL with Drupal 7's query builder?

Tags: 7, database

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ('myfield1' = 'someval1' AND 'myfield2' = 'someval1')
   OR ('myfield1' = 'someval2' AND 'myfield2' = 'someval2')
   OR ('myfield1' = 'someval3' AND 'myfield2' = 'someval3')
```

I'm trying to do this with a foreach() loop:

```
foreach($mywords as $w)
{
  $myquery
    ->condition('myfield1', $w)
    ->condition('myfield2', $w);
}
```

Each iteration of the loop, however, should add the next set of conditions.

Comment: Haven't worked much with drupal 7, but can you pass an array to condition? If not you should be able to add the conditions like you are in the example. I dont see why not.

Comment: also try do `print (string)$myquery;` to see what it's creating. It looks like drupal has a built-in toString method to convert it to the actual query.

Comment: I checked the toString and the above produces AND's instead of OR's where I need them

Comment: Try db_or()->condition('myfield1', $w)->condition('myfield2', $w);

Comment: Actually you may have to do this $myquery->db_or()->condition(condition('myfield1', $w)->condition('myfield2', $w)); It's a condition inside a condition.

Comment: that gives me: Fatal error: Call to undefined method SelectQuery::db_or()

Comment: `db_or()` is a function, not a method of `SelectQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$query = db_select('mytable', t)->fields('t');
$condition = db_or();
foreach($mywords as $w {
  $condition->condition(db_and()->condition('myfield1', $w)->condition('myfield2', $w));
}
$result = $query->condition($condition)->execute();
```

This is not tested but should work.

For reference, see [`db_or`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_or/7) and [`db_and`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_and/7)

Comment: thanks again!  How did you learn so much about Drupal? (serious question)

Comment: @user1750 It's my work and my hobby. I spend a lot of time working with Drupal one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you add in that way are added using and "AND" operator; see the code of the constructor of the `SelectQuery()` class, and [SelectQuery::condition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3acondition/7)

```
  public function __construct($table, $alias = NULL, DatabaseConnection $connection, $options = array()) {
    $options['return'] = Database::RETURN_STATEMENT;
    parent::__construct($connection, $options);
    $this->where = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
    $this->having = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
    $this->addJoin(NULL, $table, $alias);
  }

  public function condition($field, $value = NULL, $operator = NULL) {
    $this->where->condition($field, $value, $operator);
    return $this;
  }
```

This means you need to call `myquery->condition()` only once, or the resulting query will use "AND" between the conditions. `SelectQuery::condition()` accepts also an instance of [DatabaseCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/class/DatabaseCondition/7), such as one returned from [db_or()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_or/7) and [db_and()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_and/7); both the functions are helpers build on the constructor of `DatabaseCondition`.

```
function db_and() {
  return new DatabaseCondition('AND');
}

function db_or() {
  return new DatabaseCondition('OR');
}
```

The code should then build a `DatabaseCondition` object, and pass it to `myquery->condition()`.